# Xcode Skip Install

Tags: xcode

I am creating an application using libraries that I also created. When I attempted to compile my application using libraries set with `"Skip Install" = YES`, it worked when my destination was a simulator, but failed when my destination was an actual device `(my phone)`. When I attempted to compile my application using libraries set with `"Skip Install" = NO`, it worked when my destination was an actual device `(my phone)`, but failed when my destination was a simulator. How can I build my libraries so that I can compile my application that uses these libraries independent of which destination I am using. It's kind of confusing, so let me know if anyone needs clarification.